# Laravel default user table

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.2 and want to change default user table's columns. I wrote 
in the CreateUsersTable

```
   public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->string('role');
        $table->string('info');
        $table->string('age');
        $table->string('hobies');
        $table->string('job');
    });
    }
```

and i run these commands in the git bash but user table didn't change.

```
    php artisan migrate:refresh
    php artisan migrate
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should run `composer dumpauto -o` after running `php artisan migrate` command to register new migrations, so they could be rolled back.

Try it. If it will not work, try to delete all tables, including `migrations` and run this command:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change what it inside of `Schema::create` and delete your `Schema::table`

Then, you need to implement tour `down()` mehod and add `Schema::drop('users');` in order to drop your table when you run `migrate:refresh`.

You can read the 'Database migrations' in the laravel documentation for further details.

Answer (score 0):

create new migration file and do something like this

```
public function up() {
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE user ADD some_field INT');// your query here
}

php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

delete the first statement and leave last one only .
then run php artisan migrate:refresh